# merge CSV files with xarray python

Tags: python, csv, merge, nan, python-xarray

I have three csv files that they have the same format but they are for deferent times. I created a 3-dimensional dataset `(datetime, lat, lon)` with xarray with first csv file. In the next step, I want to merge other csv files into my xr dataset. You can see my codes in following.
**Problem**: In final `xr dataset` I have `nan` values for variables. What is the error(s)?

Data sample in each csv file in diferent Lat and long but in same times.

`Lat;Lon;Alt;# Date;UT time;Temperature;Relative Humidity;Wind speed;Wind direction;Short-wave irradiation
29.893;48.859;1;2018-01-01;01:00;290.09;59.83;1.67;174.74;0.0
29.893;48.859;1;2018-01-01;02:00;289.72;66.13;2.06;166.59;0.0
29.893;48.859;1;2018-01-01;03:00;289.34;74.27;2.5;161.42;0.0
29.893;48.859;1;2018-01-01;04:00;289.11;82.31;2.88;158.44;4.349
29.893;48.859;1;2018-01-01;05:00;289.88;84.44;2.97;158.09;118.2629
29.893;48.859;1;2018-01-01;06:00;291.48;79.04;3.36;160.37;300.52`

Codes

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray
#import Data from .csv file
colnames = ['Lat','Lon','Alt','# Date','UT time','Temperature', 'Relative Humidity', 'Wind speed', 'Wind direction', 'Short-wave irradiation']
df = pd.read_csv('data/pnt_29.887_48.497.csv',header=0,error_bad_lines=False, names = colnames, sep=';')

# create new column based on day and time, new columnn = datetime
s = df['# Date'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + ' ' + df['UT time'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='ignore', format='%Y%m%d%H')
del df['# Date']
del df['UT time']
xr = df.set_index(['datetime', 'Lat', 'Lon']).to_xarray()
```

Make a list of csv files.

```
import os    
csv_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'H:\Anaconda_VSCode\Data'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            csv_list.append(file)
```

Merge:

```
for file in csv_list:
    #import Data from .csv file
    colnames = ['Lat','Lon','Alt','# Date','UT time','Temperature', 'Relative Humidity', 'Wind speed', 'Wind direction', 'Short-wave irradiation']
    df = pd.read_csv('data/'+ file ,header=0,error_bad_lines=False, names = colnames, sep=';')
    # create new column based on day and time, new columnn = datetime
    s = df['# Date'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + ' ' + df['UT time'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
    df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='ignore', format='%Y%m%d%H')
    del df['# Date']
    del df['UT time']
    xr_tmp = df.set_index(['datetime', 'Lat', 'Lon']).to_xarray()
    xr = xarray.merge([xr_tmp, xr])
    #xr = xarray.concat((xr_tmp,xr))
    del (xr_tmp)
xr
```

Result with `nan` values:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                 (Lat: 3, Lon: 3, datetime: 8760)
Coordinates:
  * Lat                     (Lat) float64 29.89 29.89 29.89
  * Lon                     (Lon) float64 48.5 48.55 48.6
  * datetime                (datetime) object '2018-01-01 01:00' ... '2018-12-31 24:00'
Data variables:
    Alt                     (datetime, Lat, Lon) float64 1.0 nan nan ... nan 1.0
    Temperature             (datetime, Lat, Lon) float64 288.4 nan ... nan 284.5
    Relative Humidity       (datetime, Lat, Lon) float64 62.27 nan ... nan 76.0
    Wind speed              (datetime, Lat, Lon) float64 2.63 nan ... nan 5.15
    Wind direction          (datetime, Lat, Lon) float64 184.7 nan ... nan 335.1
    Short-wave irradiation  (datetime, Lat, Lon) float64 0.0 nan nan ... nan 0.0
```

Comment: Your approach is reasonable. To diagnose what's going on, you're going to need to reduce your example significantly, preferably to something others can replicate https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports

Comment: Hi @Maximilian, I added a sample of my data. Are normal the result?

Comment: Btw [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has a nice way of combining date and time columns into one datetime: `parse_dates`, so you don't need that hack. And recursive file search is better done with `pathlib.Path('/my/path').rglob('*.csv')` than with `os.walk`. ;-)

Comment: It's not exactly reproducible, but as a way of getting started: are you sure they shouldn't be `nan`? Is there a value in your data for lat=29.89, lon=48.55, date=(whatever the 2nd date is)?

Comment: No, I am not sure, But based on your comment, It seems I have a cube with 3-dimension of Lat, Lon and Time that in the cube and my variable data, such as Temperature, cannot fill all space of the cube so I think the `nan` values are correct. Is it right? (Sorry I am new in pandas and xarray.)